# Путь программы до системного вызова

Tags: linux, c, ядро

Когда мы пишем программу на Си и подключаем библиотеку например `<unistd.h>` и делаем вызов `write()`, то это вызов библиотечной функции Си (вопрос где она лежит в linux), в которой есть вызов системного вызова write(где он лежит в линукс), а `write()` где то скомпилирован в ядре ОС. А что такое *syscall*? Как раз он и передает номер и аргументы в ос для вызова нужного кода выполнения?
Почему столько вопросов? Везде в инете написано, это интерфейс между пользовательскими программами и ядром ОС. А хочется понять, вот наша программа она дергает вот эту функцию, та в свою очередь вот эту... А там еще бывает linux-gateway это вот прослойка между этим и этим. И в итоге системный вызов это код в ядре для исполнения в ring0? Можно ли напрямую вызвать системный вызов без библиотеки?

Comment: А потом у вас появятся ещё вопросы поо трамплины (когда вызов из 32-битного окружения в 64-битное ядро) и тому подобные. Может какую литературу почитаете? С практической точки зрения вы можете запустить `perf` и всё увидеть.

Comment: @0andriy можете посоветовать? Читаю Таненбаума и по ходу возникают вопросы.

Comment: такие книги, как Таненбаума, Кнут или Кормен вначале нужно прочитать как "художественную литературу". То есть, не понятен какой то момент - прочитали по диагонали, поехали дальше. А через месяц-другой начнем приходить понимание, когда пазл немного сложится. И потом уже читается повторно, но в тех местах, где не понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Просто так взять и позвать (через call) "ядерную" функцию нельзя - обычно они работают на другом уровне защиты. И если можно было бы просто так позвать, то система безопасности ядра была бы под угрозой. Именно syscall и решает эту проблему. А вот как именно он устроен - это другое дело.

В Linux для x86 долгое время применялось 128 прерывание (0x80). Когда срабатывает прерывание, то процессор вызывает "специальную подпрограмму", которая просто вызывает соответствующую функцию ядра, но уже в на уровне ядра. Как стает понятно, что именно вызывать? вызывающая программа оставляет в регистрах процессора данные об этом. Например, в eax хранится номер нужной функции (их можно подсмотреть в файлах /usr/include/asm*/unistd.h и они имеют вид

```
#define __NR_connect 203
__SYSCALL(__NR_connect, sys_connect)
```

файлов может быть несколько - они платформенно-зависимые)

И так как теперь процессор находится на уровне ядра, а пользовательская программа "поставлена на паузу", ядро может для начала понять, а нужно ли что то делать, может вообще лучше прибить приложение. А потом запланировать выполнение задач пользователя. И когда будут результаты, разместить в нужных регистрах и дать указание планировщику задач поставить задачу на выполнение. А для самой задачи как будто ничего и не произошло, но результаты уже есть.

Если подобных прерываний нет (какая-нибудь экзотическая платформа), то используют другие приемы. Например, какую то несуществующую команду. Процессор генерирует исключение и оно перехватывается. а дальше по известной описанной выше схеме.

Потом поняли, что некоторые функции так "невыгодно" вызывать. Например, узнать текущее время (тут нет проблем с защитой ядра, это же не открытие какого то файла). И начали придумывать, как это ускорить. В результате начали появляться новые способы, некоторые даже являются инструкциями процессора. Например, amd придумала syscall/sysret.

- почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/347596/

Comment: «какая небудь» ? Буква ё где?

Comment: а что, уже правописание в России поменялось и Ё теперь обязательна?

Comment: С каких пор "-нибудь" через ё пишется? :D

Comment: вот и я удивляюсь.

Comment: Ох, это два разных вопроса. И буква Ё не просто так же в алфавите. Русский SO как всегда (vomit smile here)...

Comment: да. но почему то носители русского ее не уважают. Ну не нравится она им. Я одно время писал, а потом меня поправляли, мол не для детей же пишешь.